# Trying to send a message from websocket inside the same port

Tags: go, websocket, rabbitmq, gorilla

I'm writing a chat using WebSocket with gorilla https://github.com/gorilla/websocket

It's working. But now I need to send a message from a consumer of rabbitMQ that I created. The idea is to be a Bot that answers some questions.

The problem is. That I don't know how to send a message without been using a WebSocket dial request which doesn't work, it giver this error.

```
dial:websocket: bad handshake
```

Should I create an separated go main with a different port so I can send the message? Or is it possible to do it inside the same main package?

This is the websocket code

```golang
package socket

import (
    "chatGo/src/domain/message"
    "chatGo/src/domain/message/repository"
    "chatGo/src/infrastructure/queue"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "github.com/novalagung/gubrak/v2"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

const messageNewUser = "New User"
const messageChat = "Chat"
const messageLeave = "Leave"

const maxMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 // 1kb

var connections = make([]*webSocketConnection, 0)

type payload struct {
    Message string
}

type response struct {
    From    string
    Type    string
    Message string
}

type webSocketConnection struct {
    *websocket.Conn
    Username string
}

func Execute(c *gin.Context, db repository.GormDB, qBroker *queue.Broker) {
    upgrader := websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  maxMessageSize,
        WriteBufferSize: maxMessageSize,
    }

    currentGorillaConn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(c.Writer, "Could not open websocket connection", http.StatusBadRequest)
    }
    username := c.Query("username")
    currentConn := webSocketConnection{Conn: currentGorillaConn, Username: username}
    connections = append(connections, &currentConn)

    go handleIO(&currentConn, db, qBroker)
}

func handleIO(currentConn *webSocketConnection, db repository.GormDB, qBroker *queue.Broker) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            log.Println("ERROR", fmt.Sprintf("%v", r))
        }
    }()

    messageEntitiy := message.NewMessage(currentConn.Username, messageNewUser, "")
    broadcastMessage(currentConn, messageEntitiy)

    messageStr := fmt.Sprintf("User %s: connected", currentConn.Username)
    messageEntitiy = message.NewMessage(currentConn.Username, messageNewUser, messageStr)
    db.Create(messageEntitiy)
    for {
        payload := payload{}
        err := currentConn.ReadJSON(&payload)
        if err != nil {
            if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "websocket: close") {
                messageEntitiy := message.NewMessage(currentConn.Username, messageLeave, "")
                broadcastMessage(currentConn, messageEntitiy)
                ejectConnection(currentConn)
                messageStr := fmt.Sprintf("User %s: disconnect", currentConn.Username)
                messageEntitiy = message.NewMessage(currentConn.Username, messageLeave, messageStr)
                db.Create(messageEntitiy)
                return
            }

            log.Println("ERROR", err.Error())
            continue
        }

        trimStr := strings.TrimSpace(payload.Message)
        splitStr := strings.Split(trimStr, "=")
        if splitStr[0] == "/stock" {
            _ = qBroker.PublishMessage("bot-send", splitStr[1])
        } else {
            messageEntitiy := message.NewMessage(currentConn.Username, messageChat, payload.Message)
            db.Create(messageEntitiy)
        }
        broadcastMessage(currentConn, messageEntitiy)
    }
}

func ejectConnection(currentConn *webSocketConnection) {
    filtered := gubrak.From(connections).Reject(func(each *webSocketConnection) bool {
        return each == currentConn
    }).Result()
    connections = filtered.([]*webSocketConnection)
}

func broadcastMessage(currentConn *webSocketConnection, message message.Message) {
    for _, eachConn := range connections {
        if eachConn == currentConn {
            continue
        }

        eachConn.WriteJSON(response{
            From:    currentConn.Username,
            Type:    message.Kind,
            Message: message.Message,
        })
    }
}
```

I tried this code to send an message using dial

```golang
var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:8081", "http service address")
    test2 := func(msg string) {
        u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: *addr, Path: "/echo"}
        log.Printf("connecting to %s", u.String())

        c, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("dial:", err)
        }
        defer c.Close()
        err = c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(msg))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("write:", err)
            return
        }
```

Edit 1:

It was missing the handler. I fixed this with the correct handler.

But now If I send I get this error

`u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: *addr, Path: "/socket/ws?username=Bot"}`

`ERROR invalid character 'T' looking for beginning of value`

But my idea would be to send with and Query param, but when I do a get a bad handshake 404

`u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: *addr, Path: "/socket/ws?username=Bot"}`

`dial:websocket: bad handshake 404`

Comment: Is `Execute` being called when you attempt to connect? My initial guess (you have not included all code) would be that you don't have a route for `/echo`  ([e.g. `http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)`](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/server.go#L52)). [Checking `resp`](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/62) (second value returned by `Dial`) should provide extra information. Note that if this is all within the same program consider using a channel rather than establishing a websocket connection to yourself.

Comment: Brits, thank you for the answer. I have fixed this problem. But still is not working. I edited the question

Comment: I suspect that error is from `encoding/json` but there is really insufficient info to debug further. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); I suspect that you will find the issue whilst creating the example. Note that replacing the text `ERROR` to something more identifiable is likely to help you to locate the issue.